Blue/Green Deployment: How to handle global resources, like file stores, (publish/subscribe) subscriptions, etc

Blue/Green Deployment: How to handle global resources, like file stores, (notification) subscriptions, etc.

I have implemented blue/green deployment for my application. However, while it has many benefits, it also come with complexity.
How should I handle global resources, like file stores, (publish/subscribe) subscriptions, etc?

I don't want users' files to suddenly become unavailable after switching from one environment to another.
I don't want to have a race condition, where both environments subscribe to events on the same subscription. But creating multiple subscriptions results in duplicate work, with side effects, as both environments execute

